# What does "userland assertion library" mean in node.js documentation?

Tags: node.js

Documentation of [node.js `Assertion Testing`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/assert.html) has below lines:

> This module is used so that Node.js can test itself. It can be
>   accessed with `require('assert')`. However, it is recommended that a
>   **userland assertion library** be used instead.

What does "userland assertion library" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means some 3rd party library not bundled with NodeJs itself (One you have to `npm install` to get)

E.g

http://chaijs.com/api/assert/

Comment: Any idea why it is suggested to download 3rd party one and not use the native one?

Comment: Actually no.  If it has the functionality you need I'm not sure why they'd not want you to use it.  

The API stability has been marked as "locked" so it shouldn't change.